# Angular 4 How to redirect page after logout?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know this has been answered previously but I'm not satisfied with the answers given.

My problem is simple, the user want to logout.

If it's on a page that required to be login (set in auth.guard.ts with auth.service.ts) and the user logout I want him to be redirected to home.

**However** if he is on a safe page I don't want to redirected him.

I could use the AuthGuard but I don't want to reload the page, so no:

```
location.reload()
```

What's my option ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
.....

constructor(private router:Router, authService: AuthService){}
  //toastMessagesService: ToastMessagesService){} if you have one
....

onLogOut(){
  authService.logOut(); 

  if (this.router.url==="/admin"){
        //this.toastMessagesService.show("Logged out"); // display a toast style message if you have one :)
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]); //for the case 'the user logout I want him to be redirected to home.'
  }
  else{
   // Stay here or do something
   // for the case 'However if he is on a safe page I don't want to redirected him.'
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find following redirection code hope it helps

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import {Router} from '@angular/router';

  export class LogoutComponant {
    title = 'Logout';


constructor(

    private router: Router,

) {}

onLogout() {
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can redirect the user when he logs out to home like this.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
    constructor( private _router: Router){}

    authSignOut(){
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        this._router.navigate(['home']);
    }
}
```

About the rest, I'm bit confused... could share your code?

Comment: I don't want to redirect him if he is on a page that doesn't required to be login. Let's say I got three pages /home, /admin and /content. If the user logout on /admin I want to redirect him to /home. If he logout from /content I don't want to redirect him. With your solution I redirect him whatsoever.

Comment: create a function just for that like authSignOutContent() and dont redirect... or pass a param to your service to redirect just when the param is true.. could that solve your problem